# Issue with registerReceiver

Tags: android, bluetooth

The code is not entering into the `registerReceiver` function. Can you help me please (or recommend a code sample I could go through)? I am trying to find Bluetooth devices available around.

```
package com.example.mahe.toddler;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.bluetooth.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main_Page extends AppCompatActivity {

public BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
private OutputStream outStream = null;
private ArrayList<String> mDeviceList = new ArrayList<String>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main__page);

    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    btAdapter=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    findViewById(R.id.off).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if(btAdapter==null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(Main_Page.this, "Bluetooth not enabled phone.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                if (btAdapter.isEnabled())
                {
                    btAdapter.disable();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), action,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action))
            {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                mDeviceList.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                Log.i("BT", device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, mDeviceList));
            }
            else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action))
            {
                Log.v(" ","discovery Finished ");
            }
        }
    };
    findViewById(R.id.on).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if(btAdapter==null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(Main_Page.this, "Bluetooth not enabled phone.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                if (btAdapter.isEnabled())
                {
                    //do nothing
                    btAdapter.startDiscovery();

                }
                else
                {
                    //Prompt user to turn on Bluetooth
                    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);

                    btAdapter.startDiscovery();
                    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
                    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);



                }
            }
        }
    });


}
```

}

Comment: you can register the broadcastreceiver outside the OnClickListener. Otherwise your activity will try and register the already registered receiver every click. Also, make sure to deregister the receiver after it is no longer needed.

Comment: The code does not enter the action found part of code...........i rechecked to find any available devices around by the bluetooth of phone and i can find a few..where as through the app i built it is unable to ...can u help me out?